# Kotlin check if any CheckBox isChecked

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Is there a simple way of making this? I have around 16 of these CheckBoxes.

```
 kartBox1.setOnClickListener{
            if(kartBox1.isChecked){kartBox1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check_button_checked)}
            else{kartBox1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check_button_unchecked)}}
    kartBox2.setOnClickListener{
            if(kartBox2.isChecked){kartBox2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check_button_checked)}
            else{kartBox2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check_button_unchecked)}}
```

Comment: If you use setOnCheckedChangeListener instead of setOnClickListener, you already have a boolean parameter indicating whether the CheckBox has been checked or not, so you can spare yourself to verify the state on the CheckBox inside the listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically create list of those buttons and loop through it with foreach and add listeners with all needed checks.